Updating a websocket connection in a single thread in Flask application
I have a flask up with an endpoint like below
@app.route('/update_tokens', methods=['POST'])
async def update_tokens():
    # global variables

    data = request.get_json()
    auth_token = data['auth_token']
    pragma_cache = data['pragma_cache']
    print("Auth token updated:", auth_token)
    print("Pragma cache updated:", pragma_cache)

    with open("credentials.txt", "w") as file1:
        file1.write(f"{auth_token}\n{pragma_cache}\n")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    if user_ws:
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, user_ws.close)

    headers['authorization'] = auth_token
    headers['pragma-cache-local'] = pragma_cache

    #updating some other stuff ...
    
    print('USER_ID: ' + user_id)

    # Create a new task for updating the display list
    #update_task = asyncio.create_task(update_display_list(user_response_as_json)) 
    #await update_task

    # Reuse the existing thread pool to create the WebSocket connection
    
    
    # Start and stop the WebSocket connection within the route
    await loop.run_in_executor(ws_executor, functools.partial(create_websocket_connection_wallet, ws_url, loop))
    return jsonify({"message": "Credentials updated successfully"}), 200

def create_websocket_connection_wallet(url, loop):
    global user_ws

    def on_close(ws):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)  # Stop the event loop when the WebSocket closes

    user_ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_url, on_message=user_handler, on_close=on_close)
    user_ws.run_forever(reconnect=5)
    print("WebSocket wallet opened. Subscribing to channels...")
    return user_ws

This endpoint works actually and it does everything i want it to do but the endpoint is not returning a success response back to frontend that is my problem.
Any help or guidance would help me a lot
I tried creating multiple threads but it would create infinitly many threads i am stuck with this final approach and couldnt figure out any other way.
